# Order of Hom$(D_n,\mathbb{C}^*)$

Tags: group-theory

What is the order of Hom$(D_n,\mathbb{C}^*)$?

I know that $D_n/[D_n,D_n]$ is isomorphic with $\{\pm 1\}$ if n is odd and isomorphic with $V_4$ if n is even. And I know that $\#D_n=\#D_n/[D_n,D_n]$. How can I use these to determine the order of Hom$(D_n,\mathbb{C}^*)$?

Also: can I use the fact that $\#G=\#G/[G,G]$ through the composite function $G\rightarrow G/[G,G]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ where the second arrow is a homomorphism to get #Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C})$ and Hom$(S_n,\mathbb{C}^*)$?

I know that there was already a question about this, but I would like to see how this can be solved using these data.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon G\to H$ is a homomorphism and $H$ is abelian, then
$$
f(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=f(x)f(y)f(x)^{-1}f(y)^{-1}=1
$$
and so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in\ker f$. Thus $[G,G]\subseteq\ker f$ and $f$ induces a homomorphism $\bar{f}\colon G/[G,G]\to H$.

Thus the number of homomorphisms $D_n\to\mathbb{C}^*$ is the same as the number of homomorphisms $D_n/[D_n,D_n]$.

If $n$ is odd, then this group is $C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$. The elements in $\mathbb{C}^*$ with order a divisor of $2$ are $1$ and $-1$, which means there are two homomorphisms $D_n\to\mathbb{C}^*$.

If $n$ is even, this group is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$, so the homomorphisms are four. Why?